# How do I get the DOM node of the element with a clicked action

Tags: ember.js

I need to micro-manage the class names on a `<span>` element which has an action on it. It looks like this:

```
<span {{action 'sortChars'}} {{bindAttr class="active:active direction:up"}} class="carrot"></span>
```

But since you cant combine static and dynamic bindAttr attributes, or have the same attribute specified normally and with bindAttr; I need to add and remove the classes myself with jQuery....

All I need is to be able to get the DOM node of the clicked element...

This is my action sortChars function inisde my ArrayController

```
sortChars: function(){
  target = this.get('target');
}
```

target doesnt work... i get a bunch of ember stuff

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine static and dynamic class names with `{{bindAttr}}`. There is a good explanation in the [Ember Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_bind-attr).

**Your Solution (1.0 RC7 and below):**

```
<span {{action 'sortChars'}} {{bindAttr class=":carrot active:active direction:up"}}></span>
```

**Only dynamic:**

```
<img {{bind-attr class="view.someBool:class-name-if-true:class-name-if-false"}}>
```

**Only static:**

```
<img {{bind-attr class=":class-name-to-always-apply"}}>
```

**Static and dynamic:**

```
<img {{bind-attr class=":class-name-to-always-apply view.someBool:class-name-if-true view.someProperty"}}>
```

Comment: when did they switch from bindAttr to bind-attr, cuz i have r.c. 7 and im gettin an error for bind-attr. And bower thinks this is the latest

Comment: Ah i did oversee that one. This has just been introduced with RC8 -> http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html